# Shortest string expressions stable under deleting quotes

Tags: code-golf, string

Forgetting quotes can lead to certain problems.
For example, in Scala the two expressions:

```
"("+("+")+(")+(")+")"
 ("+("+")+(")+(")+")
```

differ only in starting and ending quotes, but they respectively yield the result:

```
(+)+()
+()+()+
```

But this expression in scala almost has the desired property:

```
def m="+m+"
""+m+""
```

Your task is to **write the shortest expression surrounded with quotes**, such that if we remove the outer quotes, the **expression still returns the same string**.

Key points:

- Your language must support "..." as string literals
- The program has to contain at least three characters
- You are not allowed to define a context outside of the quotes themselves (as I did for m)
- You are not allowed to use other delimiters for strings, e.g. no `"""`, no `'`.
- Both expressions should *return strings*.
- Shortest code wins (counting the quotes themselves)

Comment: return or output? can we do either? Also, how is "quine" related to this?

Comment: This problem isn't even a little quineish.

Comment: @boothby But now it's a completely different question.

Comment: @Howard I changed only the title to reflect the content of the question.

Comment: @Quincunx: Both return or output, but it should be a string. I added a line to describe it. The relation with quines is that solutions somehow encode a part of the program in a string. Ok I agree it's more a far-distant cousin relationship.

Comment: And besides, if you manage to write a quine without quotes, then encompassing it with quotes would be an answer (see Befunge answer).

Comment: What is a “program” in the sense of your question? Your examples look like you were referring to *expressions*, i.e. part of a program. After all, a complete stand-alone executable program will hardly “return” anything except perhaps for an exit code. Programs usually print things. But this is not completely clear, and clarification of that point might make things clearer.

Comment: Ok I updated. It should be an expression.

Comment: @MikaëlMayer when are you going to accept an answer (the shortest valid solution: [mine](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18109/9498) or [MvG](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18105/9498)'s)?

Comment: yes you're right. I thought that your program did not return a string. Updated.

Comment: @MikaëlMayer Next time, use the @ notation, I had no idea you told me that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Befunge 98 - 3, 4, 6, 17

In these programs, I'll assume you just want to get a string, but you don't care if the program terminates. In other words, you want a code snippet that can be placed in the code somewhere. (Note: in Befunge, whatever is on the stack is a string. It is also a number)

This code snippet must be placed on the first part of the first line.

```
"g"
```

When the quotes are removed, `g` acts like `00g`, so it pushes a `g`. Either way, it pushes a `g`.

```
""""
```

Works in Befunge 93 as well; it always pushes nothing.

This one is more interesting

```
""z"z"
```

It will always push `z`. `z` is a no-op so although the IP executes the command, it does nothing (I could have used  , but `z` is more interesting).

This one only has one set of `"`, and is quine-like:

```
">:0g\1+:f`1+jb<"
```

It always pushes the contents of the string, but when the quotes are removed, it does it in a quine-like way. This must be placed on the first part of the first line, but adjustments can be made to put it elsewhere

Comment: I updated the question so that it removes the first case: "Both programs should return strings."

Comment: @MikaëlMayer No, the first case is not removed. Both programs `"g"` and `g` return strings, one is `g`, and the other is `g`.

Answer (score 14):

## C  (4 chars)

The expression

```c
""""
```

satisfies the minimal requirement of three characters. It encodes the empty string, no matter even if you omit one level of quotes:

```c
 ""
```

If you want the resulting string to be at least three characters, here is an expression of length 10 which results in three characters of string, namely three spaces:

```c
""   "   "
 "   "
```

If you don't like spaces either, here are four printable characters in a length 12 expression:

```c
""/**/"/**/"
 "/**/"/**/
```

Putting these expressions into a small program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define CASE(s) printf("'%s'\n", s)
int main() {
  CASE("""");
  CASE("");
  CASE(""   "   ");
  CASE("   "   );
  CASE(""/**/"/**/");
  CASE("/**/"/**/);
}
```

Output:

```
''
''
'   '
'   '
'/**/'
'/**/'
```

Answer (score 4):

## Shell (3 chars)

```
"w"
w
```

Both execute the [command `w`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/w).

Comment: Seriously?!?  How many seconds of my life have been wasted typing `who`?

Comment: The question doesn't ask you to execute a command, it asks you to return a string.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: The way I read it, it asks for an *expression* which can be interpreted in two ways with the same meaning either way. So the *expression* above will do that. It is when you type that expression as the sole argument on an otherwise empty command line that the expression gets interpreted as a command name and executed. You could just as well use that expression as an argument to something else, e.g. to `echo`.

Comment: @boothby: assuming your typing speed is the same as mine, about 0.15 seconds per invocation of `w`.

Comment: I updated the question: "Both programs should return strings."

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, <s>28</s> <s>27</s> <s>15</s> 12 (6 if result can be non-string (still works with output))

This one's pretty interesting.

```
"+"*1+"+"+""
```

The basic explanation is that `"string" * 1` is `NaN`, and `+"string"` is also `NaN`. Therefore, it results in the string `"NaN+"` with or without the outside quotes.

For further explanation, it gets parsed as `("+" * 1) + ("+") + ("")` with the outside quotes, and `(+ "*1+") + "+"` without.

The version that works if the output can be non-string:

```
"+"*""
```

Which does work when outputting (as JavaScript is weakly typed):

```
alert("+"*"") // NaN
alert(+"*")   // NaN
```

---

Old version:

```
"+".replace(/./,NaN)+"+"+""
```

With the quotes outside, it is parsed as

```
("+".replace(/./, NaN)) + ("+") + ("")
"NaN" + "+" + ""
"NaN+"
```

Without the quotes, it gets parsed as

```
(+".replace(/./,NaN)+") + ("+")
// +"any string" evaluates to NaN
NaN + "+"
"NaN+"
```

Answer (score 3):

### Perl - 4 bytes

```
"$~"
```

Test program:

```
print"$~";
print$~;
```

Ouput:

```
STDOUT
STDOUT
```

Comment: Also works with many other single-character [special variables in Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). Notably,`$0`, `$;`, `$/`, `$:` and `$^` also have a non-empty string as their default value. (So does `$"`, but `"$""` is a syntax error.)

Answer (score 3):

### Update: Python (12 chars)

program

```
""+"+""+"+""
"+"+""+"+"
```

both giving

```
'++'
```

### Python (28 chars)

program

```
"".__str__()+".__str__()+"""
".__str__()+".__str__()+""
```

both giving

```
'.__str__()+'
```

### Python (38 chars)

program

```
"".replace("+","+")+".replace("+","")"
".replace("+","+")+".replace("+","")
```

both giving

```
'.replace(,)'
```

Comment: so in python, `","")"` evaluates to `",)"` ? interesting.

Comment: yes that was also new to me, it also allows for a more compact solution (see edit).

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 40

```
"(f=function (){return'(f='+f+')()'})()"
```

When you remove the quotes, it becomes an immediately invoked function expression, and this function happens to return `'(f='+f+')()'`, which is the entirety of the string. (Absuing `Function#toString`. `;)`)

Comment: Nice usage of quine. Could you do the same without using secondary quotes?

Comment: @Mikaël Probably not, since I can't have double quotes inside double quotes :-P

Comment: @MikaëlMayer I made a version (completely different one) without secondary quotes! :D http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18188/3808

Answer (score 3):

### [huh?](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Huh?), 7

```
"Ouch!"
```

It works because both `"Ouch!"` and `Ouch!` are both invalid files, so the interpreter will return `Ouch!`

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell, 4 chars

```
"$?"
$?
```

Output:

```
TRUE
TRUE
```

This uses the [automatic variable $?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx), which is a Boolean containing the execution status of the last run command. The only effect of wrapping it in quotes is that it is converted to a string prior to being printed, which is a transparent operation.

Comment: I updated the question: "Both programs should return strings."

Answer (score 2):

### GolfScript: 16 chars

OK, since my 3-char solution `"1"` has been disqualified by a rules change, here's the straightforward solution in GolfScript:

```
"{`[46 126]+}.~"
```

With the quotes, this is just a double-quoted string literal.  Without the quotes, it's a quine.  The only slightly trickly part is that, to literally comply with the rule prohibiting alternative string delimiters, I have to encode the string `'.~'` as an array of ASCII codes `[46 126]` instead.

Comment: I updated the question: "Both programs should return strings."

Answer (score 1):

## Scala REPL (10 chars)

```
"0+"++"+0"
 0+"++"+0
```

are both returning:

```
0++0
0++0
```

**Explanation:** In the first case ++ treats the left string as a sequence of chars and concatenates the next sequence of chars and rebuilds a string.
In the second case, + converts the first and last 0 to strings.

Note that everything is even a palindrom.

### Other interesting solution using blocks (55 chars)

```
"{val o="*{val o=0;o}+".substring(9,12);val i="*0+";o}"
 {val o="*{val o=0;o}+".substring(9,12);val i="*0+";o}
```

return both smileys:

```
 ;o}
 ;o}
```

**Explanation:** See the below decomposition

```
"{val o="*{val o=0;o}+".substring(9,12);val i="*0+";o}"
--multiplied by 0=>"" --------- returns "" -----  result
 {val o="*{val o=0;o}+".substring(9,12);val i="*0+";o}
        -------- o equals ";o}"-------- -i ignored- o
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python (8 characters)

```
""""""""
```

and

```
""""""
```

both return empty string
Is based on idea of MvG

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 1, 3

```
1
"1"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWMGQC0wpGSr9/w8A)

Explanation: In Tcl, [*"quoting is a tool, not a rule"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1027366/383779)

Answer (score 0):

### TI-BASIC, 6 bytes

```
""→Str1:"
"→Str1:
```

Both of these end up storing an empty string to `Ans` (and to `Str1`). The second works because storing to a variable also stores to `Ans`.

I also found another 6-byter:

```
"":":"
":":
```

Both of these will return `":"`.

I have checked every shorter chain matching `"[":]{0-3}"`, and none meet the specifications.